# Accessing an HDFS filesystem configured for high availability from H2O

Tags: python, hdfs, h2o

I'm trying to read data out of our Hadoop HDFS filesystem using the `h2o.import_file` python function. I've set the HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable as so:

```
import os
os.environ["HADOOP_CONF_DIR"] = "/etc/hadoop/conf"
```

When I try to read a file using the `hdfs:///path/to/my/file.txt` syntax, H2O gives me an error stating `Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1`. `nameservice1` is the configured name of our high-availability name service. It's not a single host. The `hdfs-site.xml` configuration defines how to contact the name nodes for `nameservice1`. How do I get H2O to access HDFS in this configuration?

Comment: You need to download the Hadoop-enabled version of H2O and start it with 'hadoop jar h2odriver.jar ...'

Comment: I've downloaded the Hadoop-enabled version of H2O for my cluster. Unfortunately, I'm working in a containerized environment that doesn't have the full hadoop installation. Before we go through the process of rolling out hadoop across our h2o cluster, can you explain why we need to run h2o with hadoop in order for it to connect to hdfs configured with HA? Or why it can't read from hdfs HA without running it in hadoop? If I specify one of the nameservice1 hosts in the hdfs url the import works, so clearly H2O can read from HDFS without running with hadoop.

Comment: Sure, you can also try starting h2o with 'java -cp h2odriver.jar water.H2OApp -hdfs_config /path/to/xml/file.xml [...rest of command-ine options...]'

Comment: Tom has provided the answer in details here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/DzqrX54b_Jk